# How to completely disable HTTP/1.x support

Tags: go, http2

I only want to support HTTP/2 for a new project, the client is not a browser so it's not a problem if we don't support HTTP/1.x at all.

from what I see in [golang.org/x/net/http2](http://golang.org/x/net/http2). I can use `tls.Listen` and pass the `net.Conn` to `http2.Server.ServeConn`.

But I'm bit confused about how to use `http2.Transport` here, can anyone give me an example?

Thanks

UPDATE:

This is the server part, pretty simple, it's an echo server

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
    "net/http"

    "golang.org/x/net/http2"
)

func main() {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp4", ":1234")
    panicIfNotNil(err)

    s := &http2.Server{}
    sopt := &http2.ServeConnOpts{
        BaseConfig: &http.Server{},
        Handler:    http.HandlerFunc(handler),
    }
    for {
        c, err := l.Accept()
        panicIfNotNil(err)
        go serve(s, sopt, c)
    }
}

func serve(s *http2.Server, sopt *http2.ServeConnOpts, c net.Conn) {
    defer c.Close()
    s.ServeConn(c, sopt)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.ProtoMajor != 2 {
        w.WriteHeader(500)
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Not HTTP/2")
        return
    }
    f, ok := w.(http.Flusher)
    if !ok {
        w.WriteHeader(500)
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Not Flusher")
        return
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello World, Echo Server")

    buf := [1024]byte{}
    for {
        n, err := r.Body.Read(buf[:])
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        panicIfNotNil(err)
        _, err = w.Write(buf[:n])
        f.Flush()
        panicIfNotNil(err)
    }
}

func panicIfNotNil(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

tested with `curl --http2-prior-knowledge http://127.0.0.1:1234 -d a=b -d c=d -d e=f`

for the client part, I'm still trying, I will update this post again when I got something.

UPDATE:

for the sake of simplicity, I don't use TLS here

UPDATE:

This is the client part

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/net/http2"
)

func main() {
    t := &http2.Transport{
        DialTLS: func(network, addr string, cfg *tls.Config) (net.Conn, error) {
            return net.Dial(network, addr)
        },
        AllowHTTP: true,
    }
    c := &http.Client{
        Transport: t,
    }

    pr, pw := io.Pipe()
    req := &http.Request{
        Method: "POST",
        URL:    mustUrl("http://127.0.0.1:1234/"),
        Body:   pr,
    }
    resp, err := c.Do(req)
    panicIfNotNil(err)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("Server return non 200, %d", resp.StatusCode))
    }

    wchan := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        buf := [1024]byte{}
        for {
            n, err := resp.Body.Read(buf[:])
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            panicIfNotNil(err)
            fmt.Printf("GOT DATA %s\n", string(buf[:n]))
        }
        close(wchan)
    }()

    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    pw.Write([]byte("hai AAA"))
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    pw.Write([]byte("hai BBB"))
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    pw.Write([]byte("hai CCC"))
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    pw.Write([]byte("hai CCC"))
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    pw.Close()

    <-wchan
}

func mustUrl(s string) *url.URL {
    r, err := url.Parse(s)
    panicIfNotNil(err)
    return r
}

func panicIfNotNil(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

but somehow it doesn't work
You can see network traffic in https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnIlQ.jpg

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried / got so far?

Comment: @lix thanks, I've update the question post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into Wireshark more closely I found the problem, it happens because the server didn't send any header frame, so the client cannot continue with more data. Just printing into `http.ResponseWriter` doesn't ensure its written into the network, it gets buffered instead, so we need to explicitly flush it.

This fixes the problem:

```
--- main.go 2018-07-25 22:31:44.092823590 +0700
+++ main2.go    2018-07-25 22:32:50.586179879 +0700
@@ -43,6 +43,9 @@
        return
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
+   w.WriteHeader(200)
+   f.Flush()
+
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello World, Echo Server")

    buf := [1024]byte{}
```